# PHPUnit\DBUnit\ namespace not defined

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I updated my composer.json file to include dbunit:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^1"
},
```

I ran composer and it updated my installation to include dbunit (I already had PHPUnit).

But when I tried to add the TestCaseTrait namespace to my test the IDE claims it can't find that namespace.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;      <----- this works great
use PHPUnit\DbUnit\TestCaseTrait;    <----- error that namespace doesn't exist
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with this in my composer.json:

```
"phpunit/dbunit": "^1"
```

By increasing the version to ^4, the namespace is no longer unfindable. Keep this in mind, if you didn't already know about the composer json schema:

```
 The caret will update you to the most recent major version (the first number).
 ^1.2.3 will match any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.
```

Here's the working composer.json I used:

```
{
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^4"
  }
}
```